# ¿es posible usando selenium con python buscar elementos mientras aún se carga la DOM?

Tags: python, dom, selenium

¿es posible usando selenium con python buscar elementos mientras aún se carga la DOM?

La cuestión es que automaticé el envío de formularios en mi trabajo, y al enviar cada uno la página en cuestión se redirecciona a otra que tarda bastante en cargar, pero realmente no necesito que la cargue para enviar el siguiente formulario.
No me sirve usar un timeout porque el tiempo de respuesta del servidor varía demasiado, y también necesito saber que ya se ha salido de la página que tiene el "submit", como manera de asegurarme que el formulario fue enviado.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que usar la clase Wait o, la mejor opcion para mi, la clase FluentWait te ayude. Se tratan de dos clases de Selenium que intentan buscar un elemento de la pagina y si no lo encuentran esperan por un tiempo maximo prefijado. La diferencia del FluentWait es que puede volver a preguntar por el mismo elemento cada n segundos, tambien prefijado.

De esta forma intentas buscar un elemento de la pagina a la que esperas llegar durante un tiempo maximo, TIMEOUT, preguntando por el elemento cada RETRY_TIME:

```
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(RETRY_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
```